# Select default value throws an exception asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I´m developing a school project(with c#, asp.net) that recieves data input from a view with selects and others inputs(dates and text), from this view:

[View that receive data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3UWQ.png)

That have this code, the input of date(2 of them)

```
<input id="Inicial" type="date" name="Inicial" />
```

Thats the first select

```
<select asp-for="AcessoVisita" class="form-control">
                        <option value="null">Escolha uma opção para o filtro</option>
                        <option value="acessos">Número de Acessos</option>
                        <option value="visitas">Número de Visitas</option>
                    </select>
```

The other select is

```
<select asp-for="tempo" class="form-control">
                        <option value="null"> Escolha uma opção para o filtro </option>
                        <option value="day"> Dia </option>
                        <option value="month"> Mês </option>
                        <option value="year"> Ano </option>
                    </select>
```

And the last select is that, where i use a foreach cicle to create options to all "Aps" i have.

```
<select asp-for="ap" class="form-control">
                            <option value="null"> Escolha um Ap ou todos</option>
                            <option value="todos"> Todos os AP's' </option>
                            @foreach(var i in Model.Aps)
                            {
                                <option value=@i.ap_id> @i.ap_name </option>
                            }
                        </select>
```

Thats the model and the variable he have

```
public class dadosPassar
    {
        public List<L_AccessPoint> Aps { get; set; }

        public DateTime Inicial { get; set; }
        public DateTime Final { get; set; }
        public string? AcessoVisita { get; set; }
        public string? ap { get; set; }
        public string? tempo { get; set; }
    }
```

And thats L_AcessPoint structure

```
    public class L_AccessPoint
    {

        public string? ap_name { get; set; }
        public short? zone_id { get; set; }
        public decimal? latitude { get; set; }
        public decimal? longitude { get; set; }
        public string? ap_eth_mac { get; set; }
        public DateTime ts { get; set; }
        public short? ap_id { get; set; }
        public Byte? type { get; set; }
        public bool? Active { get; set; }

    }
```

I has testing what happen when i let some of the input values in the default and the code throws the following exception:
[Exception throwed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybaNK.png)

That's the return from the database
[Database return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMSJb.png)
I can verify if all of other variables dont have the default value but in the last select that throws the exception and i dont know why.

So what I'm doing wrong?
And how can i make that rigth?

Comment: One way around this is to give the property a default value as an empty list: `public List<L_AccessPoint> Aps { get; set; } = new List<L_AccessPoint>()`

Comment: I think that is not the problem because the variable Aps is receiving the correct values.
I test what you said but still the same error

Comment: You need to use the debugger to verify precisely which property is null, then. Either it's Model or it's Model.Aps

Comment: Thanks a lot i solve my problem. I was redirect to the view and i forget to pass the model.Aps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the help.

The problem I had was because I forgot to pass the model to the view.
I was rendering like that the view.

```
if(ds.Inicial >=ds.Final || ds.AcessoVisita == "null" || ds.tempo == "null" || ds.ap== "null")
            {
                return View("Filtros");
            }
```

So i solved my problem passing the dp with the view

```
if(ds.Inicial >=ds.Final || ds.AcessoVisita == "null" || ds.tempo == "null" || ds.ap== "null")
            {
                dadosPassar dp = new dadosPassar();
                var objAPs = _db.L_AccessPoint.ToList();
                dp.Aps = objAPs;
                return View("Filtros", dp);
            }
```